# PyTorch: How to create a Parameter without specifying the dimension

Tags: python, pytorch

Say I want to defined a module. In this module, the `__init__()` function will create a `Parameter` called `self.weight` without known the `input_dim` of the module. My question is, how can I expand the `self.weight` and initialize it when I first call the `forward()` function?

For example, I want my module looks like this:

```
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, out_dim):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        # I don't know the input_dim yet
        self.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(None, out_dim))
        self.init_weight = False
    
    def init_parameters(self, in_dim):
        # what should I do in this function? 
        # Is this correct?
        self.weight = self.weight.expand(in_dim, -1)
        torch.nn.init.xvaier_normal_(self.weight)
        self.init_weight = True

    def forward(self, X):
        if not self.init_weight:
            # first call, so now I can initialize the weight since I know the input_dim 
            self.init_parameters(X.shape[1])
        
        # do some forward ops
        return torch.sigmoid(torch.matmul(X, self.weight))
```

And my training code looks like this (The parameter `self.weight` is passed to the optimizer after I create the model):

```
def train(X_train, y_train):
    model = MyModel(y_train.shape[1])
    optimize = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
    loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

    for epoch in range(10000):
        optimize.zero_grad()

        prediction = model(X_train)
        loss = loss_fn(prediction, y_train)
        loss.backward()

        optimize.step()
```

Comment: Why can't you `self.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(in_dim, out_dim, requires_grad=True))` inside `def init_parameters` ?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov This is because I want my module is flexible so that it can automatically initialize their parameters when I feed them the training data in the first time. So that I can easily create a Sequential of some of these models, e.g. `torch.nn.Sequential(MyModel(out_dim=100), MyModel(out_dim=20))`

Answer (score 1):

After all, it works for me using the way I explained in the comments - to allocate the weights parameter right in the `init_parameters` function.

```
import torch

class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, out_dim):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor([0.0]))
        self.out_dim = out_dim
        self.init_weight = False
    
    def init_parameters(self, in_dim):
        self.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(in_dim, self.out_dim), requires_grad=True)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.weight)
        self.init_weight = True

    def forward(self, X):
        if not self.init_weight:
            # first call, so now I can initialize the weight since I know the input_dim 
            self.init_parameters(X.shape[1])
        
        # do some forward ops
        result = torch.sigmoid(torch.matmul(X, self.weight)) 
        print(X.shape, result.shape)
        return result
    
def train(X_train, y_train):
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(MyModel(out_dim=100), MyModel(out_dim=20))
    optimize = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
    loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

    for epoch in range(10000):
        #print('.', end='')
        optimize.zero_grad()

        prediction = model(X_train)
        loss = loss_fn(prediction, y_train)
        loss.backward()

        optimize.step()
        
batch_size, in_dim, out_dim = 100, 5, 20
X_train=torch.randn((batch_size, in_dim))
y_train=torch.randn((batch_size, out_dim))
train(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering. However, I am still wondering: in `__init__()` function, the `self.weight` is `[0.0]`, and then we pass it to the `optimizer`. After that in the first time we call `model(X_train)`, the `self.weight` would be reassigned as 'FloatTensor(in_dim, out_dim)' in `init_parameter` function. So my question is: Now, which parameter is optimized in the `optimizer`? Is the `[0.0]` or `FloatTensor(in_dim, out_dim)`?

Comment: @LuoYuanzhen I see, you might be right, it's the `[0.0]` that will likely be. In that sense it's probably unreal to pass weights into the optimizer before you initialized them. Maybe you can use a maximums in_dim, e.g. 500, which will be used to allocate weights, and then after you initilize with say 200, you would use only first 200 rows of the matrix.